# What does a PLC read if I have an unconnected input?

Tags: plc

What does a PLC read if I have an unconnected input?

I know that I can test it, but I want to know whether there is any default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default logic level is probably undefined or at best written in the datasheet of the device.

You don't want to rely on a default like this unless explicitly defined there as the reading may be influenced due to noise. PLCs are commonly used in very noisy environmnents.

Comment: I know this is an old question with an old answer, but because people might not scroll down to the other comments, I'll repeat here that PLC inputs often use simple on/off switches where "off" is electrically no different from "unconnected" except for some induced noise on a long cable run.  Therefore, unconnected digital inputs to a PLC can generally be relied on to read "0" except for safety applications.  (because of redundancy, actual fault detection, outsmarting ignorant operators, etc.)

Comment: The way they do this is usually with a pull-down resistor that requires significant current (compared to noise) to raise the voltage above the threshold.  Some inputs, especially those that take 120VAC or so, use an opto-isolator instead, which is one or two LED's that shine on a light-sensitive transistor, all sealed in a plastic case that looks like an IC chip.  Either way, it requires current to operate the input, which the induced noise can't provide enough of.  More like x-20mA except with a digital threshold in there somewhere and no regard for the actual value.

Comment: @AaronD "often", "generally", "except", "usually", "Some". So basically what you are saying is: "Check the manual."? You do make some valid points though, I would've upvoted the answer.

Comment: Okay, I made it an answer.  Enjoy the upvote.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

For digital inputs it will read zero. For analog inputs it depends - for example in 4..20mA signals you know when you have a wire break, but in 0..20mA you don't.

Comment: Is that a standard you can point to, or experience with one or more families?  This has some potential to be bad advice.

Comment: In PLC industrial world digital signals are defined as 24V for 1 and 0V for 0. Tolerance vary between vendors, but that doesn't matter here. The only important thing is that 0V on input is the same as broken wire which will also give 0V. When such a behavior is a problem, you deal with it at design time by using normally closed and normally open contacts. More info can be found at http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100723073343AAS7j0H and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay. That is why 4..20mA is the most popular analog signal standard, since you know when you have a wire break.

Comment: There are some digital input cards that can provide wire break info, but these are not standard ones. There are also Safety PLCs which provide wire break info, but again they are not standard PLCs. I deal with many vendors PLC equipment in my daily job and without specialized equipment, standard DI cards can not tell the difference between 0V on digital input and broken wire. Just imagine sending 24V through a simple switch. It will return 24V when closed and 0V when open or has a wire break.

Comment: I didn't realize 0-20mA was a standard.  I thought all such modules operated on 4-20mA for valid values, but also had the capability to read below 4mA for the specific purpose of detecting problems with the circuit (0mA == problem).  Thus they would be designated as 0-20mA capable, but the values less than 4mA are not used for valid readings... If this is not true, can you show me some examples of such devices?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if a PLC input couldn't handle a simple on/off switch in the field because that's how most of them are used.  "Off" is electrically no different from "unconnected" except for some induced noise on a long cable run.

Therefore, unconnected digital inputs to a PLC can generally be relied on to read "0" except for safety applications.  (because of redundancy, actual fault detection, outsmarting ignorant operators, etc.)  The way they do this is with a pull-down resistor that requires significant current (compared to noise) to raise the voltage above the threshold.  Some inputs, especially those that take 120VAC or so, use opto-isolators instead, which is one or two LED's that shine on a light-sensitive transistor, all sealed in a plastic case that looks like an IC chip.

Either way, it requires current to operate the input, which the induced noise can't provide enough of.  More like x-20mA except with a digital threshold in there somewhere and no regard for the actual value.

Comment: +1 In between the lines you are writing: "When in doubt, check the manual to be sure what kind of input you are dealing with".

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the design of the specific input being used.  Since many processes use interposing relays between the PLC and devices being monitored, I'd say most digital inputs are designed to treat non-connected outputs as Logic 0 or Off values, since this is exactly what you get with an open relay contact.

For transistor based inputs, having a pull-down or pull-up resistor built into the input will ensure it pulls to a predefined value if nothing is connected.

For optocoupler-based inputs, an open connection would simply leave the optocoupler's input LED un-powered, representing a logic 0.  Again, no problem with floating.

Here's an example of an AutomationDirect CLICK PLC AC input, illustrating the fact that an optocoupler is being used.  For unconnected inputs, a logic 0 would be read.

[image]

Check the specs of each input module to be sure, but it's my opinion that most would default to a logic 0 for unconnected inputs.